# Can you wipe a MacBook pro's ssd if it doesn't have a firmware password?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, recovery, find-my-iphone, find-my-mac

My MacBook Pro got stolen, and I have file vault enabled but not the Firmware password, too strange on Apple's part not to set it on by default when you set a user password or at least to raise awareness about it. I'm an advanced user but never thought about the firmware password.

Anyway, my biggest fear now is that the thief can erase the disk using recovery mode, reinstall macOS and have a new apple id configured, allowing him to bypass the "find my iPhone" notification and lock.

Is that doable? If so, that redeems the whole anti-theft features of "find my" worthless!

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, you're out of luck. If they boot into recovery mode, they can wipe the drive without going online. Even if they went online, your iCloud information is stored on the encrypted, unmounted drive so the recovery OS isn't going to log in to your account and report the location anyway. Report the theft to Apple in case the thief, or a buyer, goes to an apple store for help with your machine.